Managed configurations are null on creating work profile
We are using Android management API to enroll managed devices. We have a custom app that is required for setup. For this app we also send managedConfigurations in the policy, some string data.
To get the data are using RestrictionsManager in the app, so when the app is first opened from "required for setup" action, we create the RestrictionsManager's object to get the managedConfigurations but there is this issue that we face.
Scenarios:
When we create a fully managed device then their is not issue, custom app gets the managedConfigurations. But if we create a work-profile and set the custom app as required for setup and when the app try to get the  managedConfigurations then null is returned. 
This issue specifically arising in the Moto devices that we have for testing (Moto G32 devices). For some reason it works fine sometimes, so if we enroll the devices let's say for 15 times in work-profile, then it may work 3-5 times, this is not for sure, it may work and it may not work.
We also tried some of other manufacture's devices, OnePlus, Oppo, Realme, Redmi, etc and it seems to work fine in these devices, also tried in Genymotion emulators and it works fine there are well. However a Vivo device (Android 9) have the issue similar to Moto G32. 
Then to be sure, we also tried the Moto G32 with other MDM solution other than our own, and the Moto G32 enrolled fine there.
For some more context, we follow the documentation of Android and Management API to set the managementConfigurations and to get them in the app using RestrictionsManager. We are using the specified way to implement this feature.
    val restrictionManager = getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE) as RestrictionsManager
    val appRestrictions = restrictionManager.applicationRestrictions

    if (appRestrictions != null){
        val id = appRestrictions.getString("key")
        val baseUrl = appRestrictions.getString("key2")}

On backend:
"managedConfiguration" {
  "key": "abc123",
  "key2": "another value"

 }

So now, I am scratching my head to figure this out, what in the seven hells is going wrong. Please help out.
